# How to change the temperature of a softmax output in Keras

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, keras, softmax

I am currently trying to reproduce the results of the following article.
http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/
I am using Keras with the theano backend.  In the article he talks about controlling the temperature of the final softmax layer to give different outputs.

> Temperature. We can also play with the temperature of the Softmax
>   during sampling. Decreasing the temperature from 1 to some lower
>   number (e.g. 0.5) makes the RNN more confident, but also more
>   conservative in its samples. Conversely, higher temperatures will give
>   more diversity but at cost of more mistakes (e.g. spelling mistakes,
>   etc). In particular, setting temperature very near zero will give the
>   most likely thing that Paul Graham might say:

My model is as follows.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, batch_input_shape = (batch_size, 1, 256), stateful = True, return_sequences = True))
model.add(LSTM(128, stateful = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(256, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer = Adam(),
              loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

The only way I can think to adjust the temperature of the final Dense layer would be to get the weight matrix and multiply it by the temperature.  Does anyone know of a better way to do it?  Also if anyone sees anything wrong with how I setup the model let me know since I am new to RNNs.

Answer (score 13):

Well it looks like the temperature is something you do to the output of the softmax layer.  I found this example.

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_text_generation.py

He applies the following function to sample the soft-max output.

```
def sample(a, temperature=1.0):
    # helper function to sample an index from a probability array
    a = np.log(a) / temperature
    a = np.exp(a) / np.sum(np.exp(a))
    return np.argmax(np.random.multinomial(1, a, 1))
```

Comment: Is the last any different from `np.random.choice(len(a), p=a)`?

Comment: This is not the standard softmax with temperature as defined here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function (in the reinforcement learning section). Why is there a log being applied before dividing by temperature?

Comment: @A.D the argument `a` is actually the softmax output of the network. So we use log to reverse the softmax operation and get logit-like values. These are the kind of values on which the temperature can be applied. This is consistent with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function#Smooth_arg_max).

Answer (score 7):

The answer from @chasep255 works ok but you will get warnings because of log(0). You can simplify the operation e^log(a)/T = a^(1/T) and get rid of the log

```
def sample(a, temperature=1.0):
  a = np.array(a)**(1/temperature)
  p_sum = a.sum()
  sample_temp = a/p_sum 
  return np.argmax(np.random.multinomial(1, sample_temp, 1))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think you mean e^(log(a)/T) = a^(1/T)

Answer (score 2):

You can build your custom layer in keras to make temprature .

Code in keras will be like this and use this layer as any layer in keras like(Dense)

```
class Temperature(keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Temperature, self).__init__()
    self.temperature = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.ones(1))
    
  def call(self, final_output):
    return final_output/ self.temperature
```

Comment: You should use ``self.add_weight`` or ``tf.Variable``. In this example you are mixing Keras layers with torch parameters

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: It should be:  'class Temperature(keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Temperature, self).__init__()
    self.temperature = tf.Variable(
        initial_value = [1.], trainable=True)
    # self.temperature = tf.ones(1)
    
  def call(self, final_output):
    return final_output/ self.temperature'